# Changing an asp:textbox text using jquery.js while trying to compute for age using (Date.now - Date) Equation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

So I need to automatically compute for a person's age by javascript and show it on an asp:textbox. The birthdate is acquired by using jquery-ui's datetimepicker. I expect that I can do arithmetic functions on two date variables so I intend to calculate the age by

`var age = Date.Now - $bdate;`

What I have done is I converted my bdate to ISO-8601 format because I read that date.parse only works with ISO-8601 compliant format before trying to minus both dates.

Is there anything wrong to what I am thinking?
here's my code:

`$('#<%= txtBDate.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        var rawr = Date.parse($(#'<%= txtBDate.ClientID%>').val());
        $('<%=txtAge.ClientID%>').val(Date.now - rawr);
    });`

Comment: update I still havn't solved my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function getage() { 

var birthday = document.getElementById('birthdate').value // get the birthdate from the birthdate textbox with id = "birthdate"

var dob = birthday ; //insert birthrate into dob variable
var year = Number(dob.substr(0, 4)); //  get year from dob variable
var month = Number(dob.substr(4, 2)) - 1; //get month from dob variable
var day = Number(dob.substr(6, 2)); //get day from dob variable
var today = new Date();  // get current date
var age = today.getFullYear() - year; // calculate age
if (today.getMonth() < month || (today.getMonth() == month && today.getDate() < 
day)) {
age--;
alert(age);
}
}
```

Comment: just make function and call it on blur event of that birthdate textbox .. then return age to the textbox by selecting element id .. assuming that the textbox id is age ... so just add at end of function or on blur event this line    
   var s= 
   document.getElementById('age');
   s.value = age

Comment: oh and also one more thing .. make sure you format the date for all the fields to something like dd/MM/yyyy or whatever format you want

Comment: It looks like coding for more than 10 hrs a day takes a toll at my ability in critical thinking. anyways. thank you for this. I also had made a function somewhat similar to this. I guess I just need a break :(

Comment: your most welcome ... i know how it feels bro .. good luck with your project

Answer (score 2):

So what made me solve this problem is by calling the day off and rest for the night. I guess coding for how many hours a day makes you tired and dumb.

anyways, here's the code that I made to solve this problem

```
$('#<%= txtBDate.ClientID%>').change(function () {
        var today = new Date();
        var curYear =  today.getFullYear();
        var curMonth = today.getMonth();
        var bdate = new Date($('#<%=txtBDate.ClientID%>').val());
        var bYear = bdate.getFullYear();
        var bMonth = bdate.getMonth();
        var age = curYear - bYear;
        if (curMonth < bMonth) {
            age = age - 1;
        }
        $('#<%=txtAge.ClientID%>').val(age);
    })
```